# Как манипулировать с данными из option selected на jquery и ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Вот ситуация, у меня уже подключено к базе данных. 
Я вывожу список в  через функцию. Выглядит это вот так вот -

[image]

Теперь выбираем список, подгружается с базы данных.

[image]

Вот сам код части -

```
<?php

function fetchGenres() {
  $db = new Connection();
  $db->open();
  $genres = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM clubgenre");
  $db->close();

  $genresArr = array();
  while ($row = $genres->fetch_assoc()) {
    $genresArr[$row["code"]] = $row["category"];
  }
  return $genresArr;
}

function showCategory($genresArr) {
 echo '<p><div class="row">
           <select  name="sweets"  class="input-field col s12">
           <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the ganre</option>';

           foreach ($genresArr as $key => $value) {

               echo '<option value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
             }
             // Go to next key
             next($genresArr);

 echo '    </select>

                <input type="submit" name="entergenre" value="Delete Genre" class=" waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">

       </div></p>




       ';
}

showCategory(fetchGenres());
?>
```

**Вот сам вопрос** - При нажатии на кнопку делит, нужно что бы выбранная пользователем категория была удаленна с базы данных.
*Вот дуб дубом я. Если можно напишите часть, а если нет, то объясните поэтапно.
Буду безумно благодарным, реально уже 2 дня мучаюсь, сначала что бы заработал список с базы, теперь с этим. Я даже не до конца понимаю, почему у меня это работает.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$db = new PDO();

$genre = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sweets', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

$sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM clubgenre WHERE code=?;");
$sth->execute([$genre]);
```

Естественно решение нужно адаптировать под ваш класс работы с БД.